# Columns not staying hidden when different cell selected

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below code to hide columns based on 'NOW' date. It works when I manually run the code, but not when I open the workbook. (General - Workbook_Open)

Also, the columns do not remain hidden when I select a different cell.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
'Sub HideColumnsDate()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("B5:AF5")
        If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
            If DateValue(Format(cell.Value, "dd-mmm-yy")) < Now Then
                cell.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**What sheet looks like.**

[image: What sheet looks like.]

I have used this code to hide rows in a different workbook and it works.

I am expecting the columns to remain hidden.

Comment: Do you have a `Worksheet_Change` event going on? And do you have multiple sheets since you're not fully qualifying your range in the `Workbook_Open` event.

Comment: This line: "If DateValue(Format(cell.Value, "dd-mmm-yy")) < Now Then" can be replaced with the simpler: "If cell.Value < Now Then"

Comment: @Notus_Panda If you think about it again, the Worksheet Change event (or any other event) is not triggered when (un)hiding rows/columns.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I was more thinking about a different value being entered in A2/A4 and it doing something or as OP said selecting a different cell and thus triggering `Worksheet_SelectionChange`.

Comment: @Notus_Panda
I did have a Worksheet_Change - `'Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
'Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
'End Sub` Once I took it out, it worked a treat. Thank you for the quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

### A Workbook Open: Hide Columns With Earlier Day of Month Than Today

**`ThisWorkbook` Module**

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    HideColumnsDate
End Sub
```

**Standard Module e.g. `Module1`**

```vb
Sub HideColumnsDate()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' adjust!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("B5:AF5")
    
    Dim dYear As Long: dYear = Year(Date)
    Dim dMonth As Long: dMonth = Month(Date)
    
    Dim urg As Range, cell As Range, dValue As Variant
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) > 0 Then
            On Error Resume Next
                dValue = DateSerial(dYear, dMonth, CLng(cell.Value))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If IsDate(dValue) Then
                If dValue < Date Then ' before today
                    If urg Is Nothing Then
                        Set urg = cell
                    Else
                        Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
                    End If
                Else ' found today or later
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            dValue = Empty ' reset for the next iteration
        End If
    Next cell
        
    rg.EntireColumn.Hidden = False ' unhide all
    If Not urg Is Nothing Then urg.EntireColumn.Hidden = True ' hide

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The DateValue function input format according to Excel Help

> DateValue recognizes the order for month, day, and year according to the Short Date format you specified for your system.

Seems that this setting not correspond to the format in your code. Simply compare date like this:

`If cell.Value < Now Then`

Remark: Also take into consideration comments involving qualifying.